# Flex connection with database

Tags: java, apache-flex, flex4, blazeds

I need to write values from form in flex to an oracle database. I know i will be using the blaze DS bridge but I can not understand how to send all the parameters at once to my java class which connects to the database. I have established the connection and I am being able retrieve values from java to flex but not vice versa. Can someone help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download Blazeds turnkey server from the site.
http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/blazeds/BlazeDS

In tomcat\webapps\samples\WEB-INF\flex-src
Extract flex-src see the sample testdrive-update.